# Gridview get only one user with all equipments through mapping table

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have users table containing : PK - id, username, password.

I have three tables ( laptop, display, phone) - id - FK, series, model

I have userequipmentmapping table containing : id - PK , user_id - FK( id from users table), laptop_id - FK (id from laptop table), phone_id - FK (id from phone table), display_id(id from dislpay table), start_date, end_date.

I have mapped using the userequipmentmapping table users having equipments, but on every record i only assign laptop/display/phone and start_date and end_date.

For ex:

id / user_id / laptop_id / phone_id/ display_id / start_date / end_date

1  /    2    /    NULL   / 1        / NULL      /  05.05.2020 / 10.05.2020

2  /    2    /    3      / NULL     / NULL      /  07.05.2020 / 10.05.2020

3  /    2    /    NULL   / NULL     / 1         /  02.02.2020 / 11.11.2020

i want to be able to retrieve on one single line what equipments i have for an user_id. Is that possible ? **Thank you for any help**

[for now i get 3 rows for the above example]

Controller :

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $usermodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        
        $userquery = $usermodel->getUsers();
        
        $displaymodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $displayquery = $displaymodel->getDisplays();
        
        $phonemodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $phonequery = $phonemodel->getPhones();
        
        $laptopmodel = new UserEquipmentMapping();
        $laptopquery = $laptopmodel->getLaptops();
        
        #foreach($query as $q)
        #print_r($q);
        #       
        #die;
        
        $searchModel = new UserequipmentmappingSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
                
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'userquery' => $userquery,
            'displayquery' => $displayquery,
            'laptopquery'=> $laptopquery,
            'phonequery'=> $phonequery,
        ]);
    }
```

Model :

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\UserQuery;
use yii\db\ActiveQuery;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "user_equipment_mapping".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $user_id
 * @property int|null $laptop_id
 * @property int|null $phone_id
 * @property int|null $display_id
 * @property string|null $start_date
 * @property string|null $stop_date
 *
 * @property Display $display
 * @property Laptop $laptop
 * @property Phone $phone
 * @property User $user
 */
class UserEquipmentMapping extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user_equipment_mapping';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['user_id'], 'required'],
            [['user_id', 'laptop_id', 'phone_id', 'display_id'], 'integer'],
            [['start_date', 'stop_date'], 'safe'],
            [['display_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Display::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['display_id' => 'id']],
            [['laptop_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Laptop::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['laptop_id' => 'id']],
            [['phone_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Phone::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['phone_id' => 'id']],
            [['user_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['user_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'user_id' => 'User ID',
            'laptop_id' => 'Laptop ID',
            'phone_id' => 'Phone ID',
            'display_id' => 'Display ID',
            'start_date' => 'Start Date',
            'stop_date' => 'Stop Date',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Display]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|DisplayQuery
     */
    public function getDisplay()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Display::className(), ['id' => 'display_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Laptop]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|LaptopQuery
     */
    public function getLaptop()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Laptop::className(), ['id' => 'laptop_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[Phone]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|PhoneQuery
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Phone::className(), ['id' => 'phone_id']);
    }

    /**
     * Gets query for [[User]].
     *
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery|UserQuery
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
    
    
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(),['user_id', 'id']);
    }

    public function getLaptops()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Laptop::className(),['laptop_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    public function getDisplays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Display::className(),['dislpay_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    public function getPhones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Phone::className(),['phone_id', 'id']);
    }
    
    
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return UserEquipmentMappingQuery the active query used by this AR class.
     */
    public static function find()
    {
        return new UserEquipmentMappingQuery(get_called_class());
    }
}
```

View :

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\UserequipmentmappingSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'User Equipment Mappings';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="user-equipment-mapping-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create User Equipment Mapping', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    
    
    
    
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'formatter' => [
            'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
            'nullDisplay' => '-',],
        'columns' => [
            #['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            #'id',
            #'user.username',
            ['attribute' => 'user',
                'label' => 'Username',
                'value' => 'user.username'
                #},
            ],
            #'laptop.laptop_model',
            ['attribute' => 'laptop',
                'label' => 'Laptop Series',
                'value' => 'laptop.laptop_series'
                #},
            ],
            
            #'laptop_id',
            #'phone.phone_model',
            ['attribute' => 'phone',
                'label' => 'Phone Series',
                'value' => 'phone.phone_series'
                #},
            ],
            #'phone_id',
            #'display.display_model',
            ['attribute' => 'display',
                'label' => 'Display Series',
                'value' => 'display.display_series'
                #},
            ],
            #'display_id',
            'start_date',
            'stop_date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'header' => "Actions"],
        ],
    ]); ?>


</div>
```

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Your search function must return results from user table, then gridview will be filled by rows with users. After that for each user and each column (laptop_id, phone_id and display_id) you have to call relation  from User model - you can set new relations for example getLaptop(), getPhone(), getDisplay()

Answer (score 0):

From SQL prospect it can be something like that:

```
SELECT user_id, start_date, end_date, laptop_id as value FROM userequipmentmapping WHERE user_id = 2 and value IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT user_id, start_date, end_date, phone_id as value FROM userequipmentmapping WHERE user_id = 2 and value IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL SELECT user_id, start_date, end_date, display_id as value FROM userequipmentmapping WHERE user_id = 2 and value IS NOT NULL
```